# Change value of node according to other node in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to change value of some node.
Condition for change value is as below:

If node name is "Name1" and if keyword is n1 then change to n2
If node name is "Name1" and if keyword is g1 then change to g2

```
<maindata>
<data>
 <keyword>n1</keywod>
 <keyword>g1</keyword>
</data>

<name>
<String>Name1</String>
</name>
</maindata>
```

Also I just change the value of above nodes all other content of file are just copy, so I write code for this as below:

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

So how can I write template to change node value as mention above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add two templates:

```
<xsl:template match="maindata[name/String = 'Name1']/data/keyword[. = 'n1']">
  <keyword>n2</keyword>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="maindata[name/String = 'Name1']/data/keyword[. = 'g1']">
  <keyword>g2</keyword>
</xsl:template>
```